# UIElements inside of Wrapped RadBusyIndicator's content are null

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik

I've got an interesting UI problem. I've got a `RadBusyIndicator` from Telerik wrapped inside of a UserControl (for ease of switching to the Windows busy indicator if the Telerik one still has a memory leak). When I put content into the control, if it has anything more than a `ContentControl` in between the opening and closing tags of the wrapper control, everything with an `x:Name` attribute is null in the code behind and causes an exception when the page is loaded.

Here is a likeness of the code with names removed to protect the innocent.

The xaml...

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="Indicator">
        <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding Path=IsStatusBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" BusyContent="{Binding Path=WaitingContent, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=UserContent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>  
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind...

```
[ContentProperty("UserContent")]
public partial class CustomBusyIndicator : UserControl
{
    public CustomBusyIndicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Indicator.DataContext = this;
    }  

    public UIElement UserContent
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(UserContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserContentProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty UserContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PageContent", 
        typeof(UIElement), typeof(CustomBusyIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null)); 

    private static readonly DependencyProperty WaitingContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WaitingContent",
        typeof (object), typeof (CustomBusyIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnWaitingContentChanged));

    private static void OnWaitingContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {}

    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsStatusBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsStatusBusy",
        typeof (bool), typeof (CustomBusyIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsStatusBusyChanged));

    private static void OnIsStatusBusyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {}


    public bool IsStatusBusy
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsStatusBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsStatusBusyProperty, value); }
    }

    public object WaitingContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(WaitingContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WaitingContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like this.....

```
<CustomBusyIndicator IsStatus={Binding IsBusy}>
    <CustomBusyIndicator.WaitingContent>
        <TextBlock Text="Loading..." Foreground="Black" />
    </CustomBusyIndicator.WaitingContent>
    <Grid>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </Grid>
</CustomBusyIndicator>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**

I've now established that it is the x:Name that seems to be causing the issues. They are null in the code behind after `InitializeComponent()` is called.

Comment: As far as I understand this it has nothing to do with `x:Name`. Wait a minute, I will write down a proper answer in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deriving from `UserControl`, so what happens... let's see:

Your class inherits a public property called `Content` and exactly this property is the dedicated `ContentProperty` of the baseclass, caused by an annotation like `[ContentProperty("Content")]` at the baseclass level.

That's the reason why normaly everything you declare in the xaml-part of you userControl definition is showing up when loaded.
So when you see this...

```
<UserControl ... >
    <Grid x:Name="Indicator">
        <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" ... />
    </Grid>  
</UserControl>
```

it is technically the same as writing this:

```
<UserControl ... >
    <UserControl.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="Indicator">
            <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" ... />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl.Content>
</UserControl>
```

That means whenever you use your UserControl somewhere in your xaml and add content the way you did...

```
<CustomBusyIndicator ...>
    <Grid> ... </Grid>
</CustomBusyIndicator>
```

...you are overwriting everything that was declared inside the xaml-part of the UserControl definition (and it does not matter that you annotated another property to be the ContentProperty, this just means you set the new ContentProperty twice).

So what are your options now:

**Option Number 1: Keep UserControl as your base, but use your property `UserContent` only explicitly**
so the usage would look like this:

```
<CustomBusyIndicator ...>
    <CustomBusyIndicator.UserContent>
        <Grid> ... </Grid>
    </CustomBusyIndicator.UserContent>
</CustomBusyIndicator>
```

**Option Number 2: derive from `Control` or `ContentControl` and transform your UserControl's xaml-part into a default ControlTemplate**
that way you can use it like this

```
<CustomBusyIndicator ...>
    <Grid> ... </Grid>
</CustomBusyIndicator>
```

but you have to make sure your template is found when the xaml is parsed. I usually do the following:

- create a ResourceDictionary `CustomBusyIndicator.xaml`
- add an entry to `themes/generic.xaml` that includes the dictionary
- add `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomBusyIndicator);` to your control's constructor
- add an implicit style to CustomBusyIndicator.xaml

And this has another ramification. You cannot use named elements as easily as before: you have to write an override for `OnApplyTemplate` and get references to those named elements via `GetTemplateChild("BusyIndicator") as RadBusyIndicator;`

**Option Number 3: Keep UserControl as your base, and `UserContent` as the ContentProperty, but set the xaml-part explicitly**
so the definition would look like this:

```
<UserControl ... >
    <UserControl.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="Indicator">
            <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" ... />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl.Content>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It took me a while to fully understand what you were saying, but your second approach was right on the money. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Madviola: I thought about my statement that "you can't use a UserControl if you want to use the ContentProperty shortcut syntax", well, this is not correct. You should be able to set the xaml-part in the definition explicitly, but I haven't tried it. I added it as a third option to my answer.